# How do I change 'If Target.Address' from a cell to a range?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the following VBA for a multiselect drop down. I need to change "$C$7" to a range of C7:C42 since I'm going to have a drop down on each of these rows and I need them to have the multiselect option.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String
On Error GoTo Exitsub
If Target.Address = "$C$7" Then
        If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
        GoTo Exitsub
        Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Newvalue = Target.Value
        Application.Undo
        Oldvalue = Target.Value
        If Oldvalue = "" Then
                Target.Value = Newvalue
        Else
                Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
        End If
End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I tried different ways to write range, but continue to get an error or the multiselect option does not work.

Comment: `If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C7:C42")) Is Nothing Then`.

Comment: Your code currently assumes that `Target` is a single-cell (e.g. with the comparison `Target.Value = ""`). Once you switch to the range `C7:C42`, if `Target` refers to multiple cells, this will fail. A loop is a safe approach: `Dim cell As Range`, `For Each cell in Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C7:C42"))`... or something similar.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification. Your breakdown and suggestions worked spot on!